# ¿Cómo pedir de una tabla un elemento de cada posición ordenado por timestamp?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, pgadmin

Cual sería la forma correcta de solicitar en postgresql *todos los datos por cada posición* de esta tabla (básicamente necesito el ultimo "step" de cada posición (pos)) ??

en este ejemplo:

```
select pos, times, companies, step from history_status order by pos DESC;
 pos |           times            | companies | step
-----+----------------------------+-----------+-----
 673 | 2022-08-24 03:21:33.429016 |       292 | 3220
 673 | 2022-08-24 03:23:03.624892 |       292 | 3222
 673 | 2022-08-24 03:21:10.593225 |       292 | 3219
 672 | 2022-08-19 01:19:37.608525 |       292 | 3219
 672 | 2022-08-19 01:38:20.096511 |       292 | 3222
 672 | 2022-08-19 01:19:49.375686 |       292 | 3220
 671 | 2022-08-19 01:19:37.608525 |       292 | 3219
 671 | 2022-08-19 01:19:49.350515 |       292 | 3220
 671 | 2022-08-19 01:38:20.096511 |       292 | 3222
 670 | 2022-08-17 10:55:49.724941 |       310 | 3476
 670 | 2022-08-17 10:55:34.02915  |       310 | 3475
 669 | 2022-08-17 10:51:30.20212  |       310 | 3476
 669 | 2022-08-17 10:52:29.800695 |       310 | 3478
 669 | 2022-08-17 10:51:05.01008  |       310 | 3475
 668 | 2022-08-11 23:39:48.759836 |       293 | 3234
 668 | 2022-08-11 23:42:36.903544 |       293 | 3234
 667 | 2022-08-11 23:19:55.063745 |       293 | 3234
 666 | 2022-08-11 23:14:38.335605 |       293 | 3234
 665 | 2022-08-11 23:14:38.335605 |       293 | 3234
 664 | 2022-08-11 23:02:48.66474  |       293 | 3236
 664 | 2022-08-11 23:03:43.27225  |       293 | 3238
 664 | 2022-08-11 23:01:46.27165  |       293 | 3235
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si definimos "último" como el step con el `times` más nuevo, entiendo que podrías hacer algo así:

```
select  T.*
        from (select pos, 
                     times, 
                     companies, 
                     step,
                     row_number() over (partition by times order by step desc) as Rn
                     from history_status
        ) T
        WHERE R.Rn = 1
```

Usamos [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-row_number/) para generar un numerador que se reinicia por cada `pos` y cuyo orden es el de `times desc`, el valor 1 de este dato será la fila que buscamos.

Answer (score 0):

Sería usando el LAST_VALUE

```sql
select distinct pos, 
                times,
                companies,
                last_value(step) over(order by pos) final_step
from history_status 
order by pos desc
```

La anterior query te botará la misma cantidad de resultados que tienes ahora por el tema de las columnas como tiempo y compañías, para solucionar esto usa CTE's:

```sql
with final_steps as ( 
  select distinct pos, 
  last_value(step) over(order by pos) final_step
from history_status)

select hs.*
from history_status hs join final_steps fs
    on hs.pos = fs.pos and hs.step = fs.final_step
order by hs.pos desc
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a ponerme a leer sobre CTES

Comment: por lo pronto no, pero tómo los CTES como un plus de la respuesta, necesito ejecutarlo en Go y estaría buscando una respuesta un tanto más simple para poder aplicarlo.